# How to remove connected components from an image while retaining some

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, label, connected-components

Let's say I have 5 connected components (labelled objects) in an image called `labelledImage` from `bwlabel`. How can I manipulate `labelledImage` so that the objects that are labelled as 1 and 4 only display, while removing the objects that are labelled as 2, 3 and 5. Then, how can I manipulate the original RGB image so that the connected components that are labelled as 1 and 4 only display.

I know how to retain a single connected component by using this line of code below. However, I don't know how to do this for multiple labelled regions.

Works.

```
connectedComponent1 = (labelledImage == 1);
imshow(connectedComponent1)
```

Doesn't work.

```
connectedComponent1and4 = (labelledImage == [1 4]);
imshow(connectedComponent1and4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `logical` indexing that way.  The simplest way is to perhaps use Boolean statements to combine things.

```
connectedCompoonent1and4 = labelledImage == 1 | labelledImage == 4;
```

In general, supposing you had a vector of elements that denote which components you want to keep, you could use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) and [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) to help you with that.  Something like this should work:

```
components = [1 4];
connected = any(bsxfun(@eq, labelledImage, permute(components, [1 3 2])), 3);
```

The above code uses matrix broadcasting to create a temporary 3D matrix where each slice `i` contains the `i`th value of the vector `components` which contain the desired labels you want to keep.  `labelledImage` is also replicated in the third dimension so the result using `bsxfun` creates a 3D matrix where each slice `i` segments out the `i`th object you want to keep. We then combine all of the objects together using `any` and looking in the third dimension.

If you don't like one-liners, you could even use a simple `for` loop:

```
components = [1 4];
connected = false(size(labelledImage, 1), size(labelledImage, 2));
for ind = 1 : numel(components)
    connected = connected | labelledImage == components(ind);
end
```

This creates an output image that is all `false`, then we loop through each value in the vector of components you want to keep and append those results on top of the result.  The end will give you all of the components you want to keep.

Lastly, you could use also use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) and determine those values in your matrix that can be found between the label matrix and the components vector and simply create your mask that way:

```
connected = ismember(labelledImage, components);
```

---

Now that you have a mask of objects you want to extract out, to use this on the original image, simply multiply each channel with the mask.  Another use of `bsxfun` can do that for you.  Assuming your image in RGB is called `img`, simply do the following:

```
outImg = bsxfun(@times, img, cast(connected, class(img)));
```

To perform element-wise multiplication, you must ensure that both matrices that are being multiplied have the same type.  I convert the mask into the same class as whatever the input image is and perform the multiplication.

Comment: How would you code this if there was a large amount of connected components (say 100). I don't think it would be efficient to type in Boolean statements one by one.

Comment: I was editing before you posted that comment. Have a look.

Comment: I seem to be getting an error at `connected = connected | labelledImage == ind` that `Matrix dimensions must agree`.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Are you sure `labelledImage` is a 2D matrix?

Comment: Yes, it `ind` is a `16x1 double` array and `labelledImage` is a `1024x1024 double` matrix.

Comment: You're using `components` wrong.  `components` should be a row vector.  I'll have to change that.

Comment: Ah yes, it works. Thanks for your help. But how would I do the same thing for the original rgb image?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. You were extremely helpful and thorough.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ismember`.

Ex:

```
A = randi(5,5);  % your connected component matrix
B = [1 4]        % list of components you want to keep

A =

     4     2     1     3     5
     2     4     2     5     1
     3     4     5     1     4
     1     4     1     3     5
     4     3     5     1     5


A(~ismember(A,B)) = 0

A =

     4     0     1     0     0
     0     4     0     0     1
     0     4     0     1     4
     1     4     1     0     0
     4     0     0     1     0
```